# Solar Panel not producing current

Tags: current-measurement, solar-cell

I am a total electronics noob trying to start out, so I purchased a small solar panel, of 110x80 mm, of 5V and 200mA. 
However, when I tried it this morning and connected it to my multimeter, I only got a reading for the voltage (around 5V, regardless of whether or not there was any light shining on it). I could not get a reading for the current (only 0), even though I put it in direct (altugh very faint, for it is morning in the winter) sunlight. These are two pictures of front and back side.

[image]

[image]

I thought that I should get some current every time there is any light, even though it could be very small. Why is this not so? Also, I thought that the voltage would be less if it is not on direct sunlight. How come this is not so?

EDIT: Here is the setup I use for measuring the current. It isnot under direct sunlight at the time of the photo, but same results occured when it was.
[image]

And this one is for the voltage:

[image]

Comment: What was your amp-meter range? You may not expect anything above 100mA in poor light. And if your range is set to let's say 10A, the lowest showing value would be 0.1A (100mA). Try to measure in a range of 0-10mA. Also, check if your amp meter is ok (I had reading of zero when fuse in my ampmeter was burnt)

Comment: I guess, you also don't have skills to use a DMM or you don't know how to measure. So you would need to post also the measurement setup.

Comment: When you connect a high-impedance voltmeter to a solar panel, you're measuring the "open circuit" voltage of the panel, which is indeed largely independent of light levels. The amount of light primarily controls the amount of current available, up to a maximum, known as the "short circuit" current. I don't know why you aren't measuring any current, unless you have the meter configured incorrectly. Can you provide more details about that? Also, the protective film, which you have not peeled off, may be blocking some of the light, but you should still be measuring *something*.

Comment: I have measured current and voltage before, so I am confident that I was doing it correctly. However, just to be safe I tested every possible range for current,and it showed 0 even for the range of 20 microamperes. I will edit the post with the configuration just to be sure, though

Comment: I have edited in the requestesd photos

Comment: Most common beginners mistake is that they blow the fuse of the current channel without even noticing it. Make sure the fuse is intact, try to measure the current of some battery powered device, but of course not shortening the battery.

Comment: Huh, I think you might be right, I took a rechargable 9V battery that I had lying around and I measured the current, and got 0. I guess I must have burnt the fuse at some point. How does it get burnt though?

Comment: @NickHeumann Most simply by connecting it directly across a solar panel, battery, PSU, etc.

Comment: Fuses may be easy to replace inside

Comment: Re, "9V battery...measured the current..." If the fuse wasn't blown before you did that, you would have instantly blown the fuse by hooking up the probes to a 9V battery with the meter set on any current scale except maybe the 10A scale.

Comment: but why? The battery says that it supplies only 175 mAh, so I thought it would be fine

Comment: @NickHeumann, "mAh" specifies an amount of energy, not an amount of current.  Current would just be "mA." I can't easily find any specification of how much current a fresh 9V battery could supply when you short it out, but you _did_ short it out by connecting it in parallel with your ammeter.  An ammeter is meant to be connected in a series circuit with the power supply and a _load_. It's suppose to tell you how much current the load _draws_ from the power supply.